# How To Unistall Ubuntu 18.04 If I have no access to Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot

How To Unistall Ubuntu 18.04 If I have no access to Windows 10?

If I succeed, next steps would be to restore the UEFI in BIOS and to reinstall Ububtu in UEFI mode.

Actually, I have Win10 in UEFI and Ubuntu in legacy mode, but Windows is not starting anymore from `grub`.

Comment: Your Windows in UEFI mode and Ubuntu is in BIOS mode? Have you not tried changing the boot mode to see Windows is booting in UEFI mode?

Comment: You have both systems on separate disks, then?

Comment: Hi both so are on same disk. From the bios I can only change the boot order but no uefi partition is available. Besides I cannot disable Legacy mode and come back to uefi because the option is locked. thanks

Comment: If you deleted the UEFI partition then OSes in UEFI mode won't boot.

Comment: The partition was not deleted it's still there but when selecting win10 from Grub it doesn't boot

Comment: You could always boot from an Ubuntu live USB, and delete non-Windows partitions. Windows has never been a requirement for this.

Comment: And if the partition is still there then you should be able to boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu, if that's the problem. You can't boot it from Grub because Ubuntu was installed in a different mode. And you don't necessarily need to delete Ubuntu partitions to reinstall in the correct mode (UEFI) either but you can if you want and no additional OS is required for that. Windows and Ubuntu have installers that can perform all the basic operations independently. More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: Hi,I'll try as suggested to delete non-win partitions from an Ubuntu  Live dvd.

Comment: My Bios is locked in legacy mode and have no uefiusb boot option available. for same reason I cannot use bootrepair in uefi mode nor try ubuntu live in uefi mode. If I can restore windows I hope I'll be able to tahe bios back in uefi mode

Comment: Hi Gabriela thanks for the link you also suggested it to me in my previous question(on same issue), maybe answer for me is in it but I probably " can't get it". I tried all adviced but with no sucess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot partition not detected in Bios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206645/boot-partition-not-detected-in-bios) Please read the instructions for "Converting Ubuntu into UEFI mode".

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to your problem, however you will wipe grub. Note that you can install it later.
First, make a windows 10 installer in ubuntu. Follow this guide: https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/
Then, boot into it.
Next, follow this guide except for steps 1-3. https://pureinfotech.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows-10/
After that's done, you can reinstall grub.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1223302)